# Cast a object to class 'double' through vars.putObject

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

In Jmeter assertion main trying to compare values of 2 variables with double data type. following script I'm using to cast a value in double

```
  double actual =  vars.getObject("Merticvalue");
  log.info ("Actual MetricValue is found to be " + actual);

  double expected=153.60
  vars.putObject("expected",expected);

  if (vars.getObject("expected") != vars.getObject("actual")) {
  props.put("testcaseExecutionStatus",5);
  String Status = props.get("testcaseExecutionStatus").toString();
  log.info("Status:"+ Status)
  return;
  } 
  props.put("testcaseExecutionStatus",1);
  String Status = props.get("testcaseExecutionStatus").toString();
  log.info("Status:"+ Status)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
   GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '153.60'    
   with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'double'
```

Comment: your code works as is, show more code to find the error

Comment: I have added complete code now. plz advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is getting `Merticvalue` value with is saved as String, you can cast it:

```
double actual =  Double.valueOf(vars.getObject("Merticvalue"));
```